# get excel range with exact row, column positions

Tags: c#, excel

I've populated an excel file starting with column 14. The important rows are from 2 to 30 let's say.

```
valueArray = (object[,])excelRange.get_Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
```

I am using get_Value to get all the values on rows and columns. The problem appears when it changes my columns from 14th to 1, 15th to 2 and so on. So if i am going to iterate with

```
 valueArray[row, column]
```

searching for the row 2 and column 14, row 3 and column 14 and so on, i will get an error because the valueArray has a different interpretation of columns.
Is there any way to get fixed positions from the excel sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simlest way is to apply an offset when iterating with valueArray:

```
for (int row = 2; row <= 30; row++)
{
    for (int column = 14; column <= 100500; column++)
    {
        object value = valueArray[row - 2, column - 14];
    }
}
```

otherwise you could use an another data structure:

```
Dictionary<Point, Object> valueArray = new Dictionary<Point, Object>();
valueArray[new Point(2, 14)] = (worksheet.Cells[2, 14] as Excel.Range).Value; // Add values in this way
Object value = valueArray[new Point(2, 14)]; // Read values
```